# How to print out an integer with the decimal shifted?

Tags: java

I have a long counter in milliseconds, and I want to print out the number of seconds. I.e, given 15 milliseconds I want to output 0.015, given 1234 milliseconds I want to print 1.234. Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to write a method?

```
// I mean this works but
public void foo(long n) {
    String res = "" + n / 1000 + ".";
    n = n % 1000;
    if (n < 100) {
        res += "0";
        if (n < 10) {
            res += "0";
        }
    }
    res += n;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Basic math? `1234 * 0.001`

Comment: Or just 1234 / 1000.0 should work?

Comment: and your void method can't return a value

Comment: @Zephyr But that would return double which doesn't always exactly represent what we want in decimal system. For instance `9*0.001` would be evaluated to `0.009000000000000001` which is not what we want to print.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", (float) n / 1000.0) ;
```

Comment: What is the point of `(float)` here? `anything/double` becomes `double` which is acceptable value for `%.3f`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, no need for a type cast